# SQLAlchemy Relationship Filter?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I do

```
table.relationship.filter( column = value )
```

to get a subset of rows for relationships?  and the same for `order_by`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [`relationship()` documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html), you can use `order_by` keyword argument with `relationship`s, to set the order that will be returned. On the same page, it mentions that you can also use `primaryjoin` keyword argument to define extra join parameters. I think that can be used for the filter you want.

[Example](https://petegraham.co.uk/TIL/sqlalchemy_relationship_filter/):

```py
tasks = relationship(
    "Task",
    order_by="Task.priority",
    primaryjoin="and_(Task.list_id==List.id, Task.completed==None)",
    back_populates="task_list",
)
```

Answer (score 52):

`relationship()` with `lazy='dynamic'` option gives you a query (`AppenderQuery` object which  allows you to add/remove items), so you can `.filter()`/`.filter_by()` and `.order_by()` it.

Comment: Link moved again: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html

Comment: Link moved again: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/queryguide/relationships.html